# Angular Push JSON data into Array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts

im trying to figure out how to push a json object into an array using typescript. I managed to do it with one value of the json object but i need to do it with the second one too.

Heres the Structure of the JSON file:

```
data = [
    {
      "value1": 8,
      "value2": 9,
      "weekday": "2023-02-27"
    },
    {
      "value1": 8,
      "value2": 9,
      "weekday": "2023-02-28"
    },
    {
      "value1": 8,
      "value2": 9,
      "weekday": "2023-03-01"
    },
    {
      "value1": 8,
      "value2": 5,
      "weekday": "2023-03-02"
    },
    {
      "value1": 8,
      "value2": 9,
      "weekday": "2023-03-03"
    }
  ];
```

And heres my code:

```
setData() {
    let data_value1:any[] = [];
    let data_value2:any[] = [];
    let labels:any[] = [];
    this.data.forEach((entry) => {
      data_value1.push(entry['value1']);
      data_value2.push(entry['value2']);
      labels.push(getDayofWeek(entry['weekday']));
    });

    this.barChartData.labels = labels;
    
    let dataSet:any = {};
    dataSet['data'] += data_value1;
    dataSet['data'] += data_value2;
    dataSet['label'] = 'Test';
    this.barChartData.datasets.push(dataSet);

    function getDayofWeek(date:any) {
      const dayOfWeek = new Date(date).getDay();
      return isNaN(dayOfWeek) ? null : 
      ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'][dayOfWeek];
    }
  }
```

It works so far if i only push one object value into the dataset array, but if i try it with += it doesnt work. What am i doing wrong?

I tried multiple stuff but nothing seems to work. I just can't wrap my head around it.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, I believe that you try to achieve a bar chart with multiple datasets.

You should have 2 different datasets:

```
[ 
  { 
    "data": [ 8, 8, 8, 8, 8 ], 
    "label": "Label 1" 
  }, 
  { 
    "data": [ 9, 9, 9, 5, 9 ], 
    "label": "Label 2" 
  } 
]
```

```js
let dataSet1: any = {
  data: data_value1,
  label: 'Label 1',
};

let dataSet2: any = {
  data: data_value2,
  label: 'Label 2',
};

this.barChartData.datasets.push(dataSet1);
this.barChartData.datasets.push(dataSet2);
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-4zfcwv?file=src/app/app.component.html)

> Output

[image]

Comment: I tried both of your options. Sadly, they don't work for me. The chart is empty now.

Comment: What do you mean "they don't work for me", what is your expected result? Try debugging by printing `console.log(dataSet['data'])` after push, what is the value? Can you create a minimal reproducible demo in StackBlitz? Thanks.

Comment: Im exporting the project to StackBlitz right now, one moment please!

Comment: Well i couldnt upload the node_modules folder because its apparently way to big. But anyways heres the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-7p9roa-7tjnze?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: Revised my answer. This should be what you need.

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i needed, just needed another dataset ... wow, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to create data for a [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/data-structures.html) bar chart with two datasets corresponding to the values for the `value1` and `value2` keys in your object array.

Here's how to do it:

```
const data = [{
    "value1": 8,
    "value2": 9,
    "weekday": "2023-02-27"
  }, {
    "value1": 8,
    "value2": 9,
    "weekday": "2023-02-28"
  }, {
    "value1": 8,
    "value2": 9,
    "weekday": "2023-03-01"
  }, {
    "value1": 8,
    "value2": 5,
    "weekday": "2023-03-02"
  }, {
    "value1": 8,
    "value2": 9,
    "weekday": "2023-03-03"
  }
];
const weekdays = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday',
                  'Friday', 'Saturday'];

function getDayofWeek(date: any) {
  const dayOfWeek = new Date(date).getDay();
  return isNaN(dayOfWeek) ? null : weekdays[dayOfWeek];
}

const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  labels: data.map(({weekday}) => getDayofWeek(weekday)),
  datasets: ['value1', 'value2'].map((k) => ({
    data: data.map((v) => v[k as keyof typeof data[number]])
  }))
};

console.log(config);
```

---

<sup>[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtA3gKBvmAIgDcEAbAVwFMBGQgLhgA4AaPAk86gJgZgE42BIgHcqVANaIAnn0LcADNwDMAWiWruAdkLsAvixi5hnSrT6t2+Uzz6Cro8VISzG8pWo3cmu-AaMONuaMliakZryM9iZikjJyiirqnnT6hsYc4dR0IUKZXFSRMACsedaxzq5EiZ6evGkBYQU5zGVEWYV2bYQV8W41ycm+MHo4ALoA3DigkLC9LhBomADkAMoUYDLLLMsAsuBbOwAq1BCHywDqVHBgVGcu28tHABYUAE730o8AYm8AludVkh3ltJjgcAAzDbAKB-cAwADmVCgABEXCAIVdJAAKRBQKiMBBgaQASkaMBm0HgLgA8pinEtbiIYGj8bikFQSQA6JGolzYklTfBvZHvMAwP4QAByCCl7OkdKxEjJAH4YGAKGQyDBGPNpBAMDJFU4waNpuAqTMIX8EUsMlBpAAHAkwZYAIwQb227DICDdVDIEEYeIQXIAtghHdjsVg9XoyagAHyI5Fo6QYpXYvUkkl5EMQZFBlYdGjbV0dbjLMbhyPR5VoZMxhwh4NIUMRqPY4gJ5PEDASGAIRYSKjpiEwB3OjHU5AYDVh-1vMZjEn6HM4PRTc2QEBkKhcsggBHYq02wVAA)</sup>